# In this documentation, what is meant by "raw text"?

Tags: html, html-lists, plaintext

I have encountered the phrase "raw text", and do not know what is mean by that Please explain to me.

I know plain text is like consists of all alphabets and numbers and punctuation, but what about raw text?

Here is the documentation phrase:

> The `<ul>` element should not hold raw text and won't automatically format raw text into an unordered list of items.

Comment: Sounds contextual. If you gave formatted text and someone asked for raw text they just want it unformatted. Generally speaking, though, Raw text is no different than plain text.

Comment: In the particular example you’ve provided, it just means that the `<ul>` tag must only contain `<li>` tags, and not just text that isn’t wrapped within `<li>` tags. “Raw text” doesn’t have a technical meaning here. It’s just semantically incorrect for a `<ul>` element to have text nodes as its child nodes that contain something other than whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

In this context, when they say "The UL should not contain Raw Text" they mean that it should be within list items `<li></li>`. For instance;

Do:

```
<ul>
<li>Coffee</li>
<li>Milk</li>
<li>Eggs</li>
</ul>
```

Don't:

```
<ul>
Coffee
Milk
Eggs
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw text is very similar to plain text. The only difference is that raw text is formatted, while plain text is formatless. Either way, don't use either in the `<ul>` tag, but rather have each item in the `<li>` tag

Incorrect

```
<ul>
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
</ul>
```

Incorrect

```
<ul>
<li>
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
</li>
</ul>
```

Correct

```
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```